# Нужен целочисленный тип данных размером в 8 и 3 байт С++, как сделать?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Нужен целочисленный тип данных размером 8 байт С++, как сделать ?
Так есть необходимость создать тип данных размером в 3 байта, как реализовать ?

Comment: Взять и реализовать, в чем проблема? Целочисленный 8-байтный может быть unsigned long long. 3-байтный через класс можно запилить, вопрос только зачем?

Comment: Нельзя использовать long и т.д. Классы тоже нельзя

Comment: Тогда это похоже на учебное задание без какой либо пользы для остальных.

Answer (score 4):

Элементарно.

```
class Int24 
{
protected:
   unsigned char m_value[3];
   ...
};
```

Comment: только без классов. Да это странно выглядит, что C++ и без классов.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков плюсы без классов выглядят куда как менее странно чем то, что вы в самом вопросе не указываете существенные ограничения.

Comment: Кстати, unisgned long для хранения m_value будет проще ;-)

Comment: На самом деле это разрабатывается программа для российских железных дорог. И нам выдали формат ЭК(Электронной карты) на основе которой мы должны ее разработать. И там довольно странные размеры в байтах и вообще все странно. Файл прикрепить могу, посмотрите сами.

Comment: `protected` данные - это зло.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков прикрепите файл, посмотрим, что там РЖД изобретает.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков, новое шубохранилище

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/gGm8UsYIpFAof

Comment: Для выделения 3 байт, я создал структуру, а в ней int varName : 24;

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков перенесите ссылку и описание задачи в вопрос

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков Вам ответили на вопрос "плохой ли вариант" - перенесите ссылку и описание задачи в вопрос. Нет? Не тот "ответ"? А иначе, у меня тогда вопросы плана, так в чем же у Вас проблема? Какие у Вас ограничения?

Comment: Да мне и ваш вариант подошел в принципе, но вы его удалили :)

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков Если вариант Вам подходил, то его необходимо было отметить галочкой. Так как этого сделано Вам не было, то я не вижу смысла захламлять посты лишними ответами. Другим пользователям потом найти ответ на свой вопрос сложнее.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков И еще... Обратите внимание, что когда кто-то пишет Вам комментарий, то указывает впереди сообщения "@имяпользователя". Это делается для того, чтобы Вы знали, что у Вас есть новый комментарий. Т.е. если Вы пишите определенному пользователю, и не указываете его имя, то он и не узнает о том, что Вы ему ответили ( у него не появится вверху в ящике входящего сообщения). Более подробную информацию об упрощенном форматировании можно получить, нажав "справка" справа от формы ввода комментария.